# How to publish review of commercial software

Tags: publications, software, software-papers

I really like software product X and been using it for >6 years. I am unaffiliated and never have been linked to company or anyone involved with X.

**I would like to publish a paper that explains why and how X can be useful to other people.** How can I do that? Are there example of this?

"[Application Note](https://www.nature.com/nmeth/about/content#application)" seems like a possible format, but I am not part of the developers. To some degree, "how to use X to do Y" seems like a novel application of an existing technology and can be written as original research paper.

---

Software is [Basecamp](http://basecamp.com/) and really helps me with research and project management. I think it merits discussion, as [we are barely starting](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-01184-9) to recognize the issue of project management in academic research labs.

Comment: FWIW, "project management in academic research" is not a new topic. If you write such an article, you should probably start with a literature review.

Answer (score 2):

There are popular magazines and some (semi) professional ones that might be appropriate for such things, but it is less likely that any scientific journal would be interested. For this reason, it is unlikely that such an article would do much for a scientific reputation. But for a person in industry, it might give them some visibility that might help in a job search.

Some people do such things on personal blogs, of course.

Comment: yeah, there are few blogs. I would like to leverage platform of a publication to help people in the field, even though it "would [not] do much for a scientific reputation"